# python3: singledispatch in class, how to dispatch self type

Tags: python, class, types, python-3.4, dispatch

Using python3.4. Here I want use singledispatch to dispatch different type in `__mul__` method . The code like this :

```
class Vector(object):

    ## some code not paste  
    @functools.singledispatch
    def __mul__(self, other):
        raise NotImplementedError("can't mul these type")

    @__mul__.register(int)
    @__mul__.register(object)                # Becasue can't use Vector , I have to use object 
    def _(self, other):
        result = Vector(len(self))           # start with vector of zeros
        for j in range(len(self)):
            result[j] = self[j]*other
        return result

    @__mul__.register(Vector)                # how can I use the self't type
    @__mul__.register(object)                # 
    def _(self, other):
        pass # need impl
```

As you can see the code , I want support `Vector*Vertor` , This has Name error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p_algorithms\vector.py", line 6, in <module>
    class Vector(object):
  File "p_algorithms\vector.py", line 84, in Vector
    @__mul__.register(Vector)                   # how can I use the self't type
NameError: name 'Vector' is not defined
```

The question may be How can I use class name a Type in the class's method ? I know c++ have  font class statement . How python solve my problem ? And it is strange to see `result = Vector(len(self))` where the `Vector` can be used in method body .

---

After have A look at http://lukasz.langa.pl/8/single-dispatch-generic-functions/
I can choose this way to implement :

```
import unittest
from functools import  singledispatch

class Vector(object):
    """Represent a vector in a multidimensional space."""

    def __init__(self, d):
        self._coords = [0 for i in range(0, d)]
        self.__init__mul__()


    def __init__mul__(self):
        __mul__registry = self.__mul__.registry
        self.__mul__ = singledispatch(__mul__registry[object])
        self.__mul__.register(int, self.mul_int)
        self.__mul__.register(Vector, self.mul_Vector)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._coords[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._coords[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._coords)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._coords)

    @singledispatch
    def __mul__(self, other):
        print ("error type is ", type(other))
        print (type(other))
        raise NotImplementedError("can't mul these type")

    def mul_int(self,other):
         print ("other type is ", type(other))
         result = Vector(len(self))           # start with vector of zeros
         for j in range(len(self)):
             result[j] = self[j]*other
         return result

    def mul_Vector(self, other):
        print ("other type is ", type(other))
        #result = Vector(len(self))           # start with vector of zeros
        sum = 0
        for i in range(0,len(self)):
            sum += self._coords[i] * other._coords[i]
        return sum

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_singledispatch(self):
        # the following demonstrates usage of a few methods
        v = Vector(5)              # construct five-dimensional <0, 0, 0, 0, 0>
        for i in range(1,6):
            v[i-1] = i
        print(v.__mul__(3))
        print(v.__mul__(v))
        print(v*3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The answer is strange :

> ```
> other type is  <class 'int'>
> [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
> other type is  <class '__main__.Vector'>
> 55
> error type is  <class 'int'>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "p_algorithms\vector.py", line 164, in <module>
>     print(v*3)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\functools.py", line 710, in wrapper
>     return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
>   File "p_algorithms\vector.py", line 111, in __mul__
>     raise NotImplementedError("can't mul these type")
> ```

`v.__mul__(3)`  can work but `v*3` can't work. This is strange From my option `v*3` is just the same as `v.__mul__(3)` .

---

Update after @Martijn Pieters's comment, I still want implement `v*3` in class. So I try this

```
import unittest
from functools import  singledispatch

class Vector(object):

    @staticmethod
    def static_mul_int(self,other):
         print ("other type is ", type(other))
         result = Vector(len(self))           # start with vector of zeros
         for j in range(len(self)):
             result[j] = self[j]*other
         return result

    @singledispatch
    @staticmethod
    def __static_mul__(cls, other):
        print ("error type is ", type(other))
        print (type(other))
        raise NotImplementedError("can't mul these type")


    __mul__registry2 = __static_mul__.registry
    __mul__ = singledispatch(__mul__registry2[object])
    __mul__.register(int, static_mul_int)

    def __init__(self, d):
        self._coords = [0 for i in range(0, d)]
        self.__init__mul__()


    def __init__mul__(self):
        __mul__registry = self.__mul__.registry
        print ("__mul__registry",__mul__registry,__mul__registry[object])
        self.__mul__ = singledispatch(__mul__registry[object])
        self.__mul__.register(int, self.mul_int)
        print ("at last __mul__registry",self.__mul__.registry)

    # @singledispatch
    # def __mul__(self, other):
    #     print ("error type is ", type(other))
    #     print (type(other))
    #     raise NotImplementedError("can't mul these type")


    def mul_int(self,other):
         print ("other type is ", type(other))
         result = Vector(len(self))           # start with vector of zeros
         for j in range(len(self)):
             result[j] = self[j]*other
         return result

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._coords[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._coords[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._coords)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._coords)


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_singledispatch(self):
        # the following demonstrates usage of a few methods
        v = Vector(5)              # construct five-dimensional <0, 0, 0, 0, 0>
        for i in range(1,6):
            v[i-1] = i
        print(v.__mul__(3))
        print("type(v).__mul__'s registry:",type(v).__mul__.registry)
        type(v).__mul__(v, 3)
        print(v*3)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This time .  `v.__mul__(3)` have error :

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 73, in test_singledispatch
>     type(v).__mul__(v, 3)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/functools.py", line 708, in wrapper
>     return dispatch(args[0].__class__)(*args, **kw)
> TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
> ```

For me static method should act like the instance method.

Comment: `v * 3` is not the same as `v.__mul__(3)`; it is the same as `type(v).__mul__(v, 3)`. See [*Special method lookup*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup).

Comment: What i code v.__mul__(3), is indeed like __mul__(v,3), Here v is the object , 3 is the type I register in ·__init__mul__· （like I bind the  second arg of this fun to dispatch）. if type(v).__mul__(v, 3) is not same . what's the difference with v.__mul__(3). In c language level ?

Comment: It is important to know that Python functions act as descriptors; see [From Function to Method](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod) and [descriptor HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html); this is how Python *binds* a function to an instance, giving you a method.

Comment: However, for *special methods* (so `__mul__` and `__add__` and `__hash__`, etc., to support creating a hash of a class and other usecases), Python *bypasses* bound methods and instead manually passes in `self`; `type(v).__mul__(v, 3)` takes the unbound function and passes in `v` as `self` directly.

Comment: It isn't clear why you are asking your mini question in your bounty message; either way, you cannot use `functools.singledispatch` on methods, because decorators always apply to the *unbound function*, not to the method, so the first argument is *always* `self`. My answer sidesteps the issue by delegating the method to a separate, outside singledispatch function instead.

Comment: so v.__mul__(v). here the true func only take one arg? That's why my `__init__mul__` can work ? Here I seem can't understand why it can make v.__mul__(v) dispatch right？ But how the 'self' arg passed in bounded function?

Comment: Your `__init__mul__` cannot work because special methods are never looked up on the instance. Python will not use those because it uses `type(v).__mul__` instead of `v.__mul__`, always. That's why I pointed you to the [*Special method lookup* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup).

Comment: So there are two issues here: `__init__mul__` won't work because you are working with special methods and those won't be taken from the instance as Python goes straight to the class and provides the `self` argument manually. And because `__mul__` is then *always* passed in a `Vector` first argument, you **cannot** use single dispatch on class methods.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You cannot use `functools.singledispatch` on methods **at all**, not as a decorator at least. Python 3.8 adds a new option, just for methods: [`functools.singledispatchmethod()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatchmethod).

It doesn't matter that `Vector` isn't defined here yet; the first argument to any method is always going to be `self`, while you'd use single dispatch for the *second argument* here.

Because decorators apply to the *function objects* before the class object is created, you could just as well register your 'methods' as functions instead, *outside* of the class body, so you have access to the `Vector` name:

```
class Vector(object):

    @functools.singledispatch
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return NotImplemented

@Vector.__mul__.register(int)
@Vector.__mul__.register(Vector)                
def _(self, other):
    result = Vector(len(self))           # start with vector of zeros
    for j in range(len(self)):
        result[j] = self[j]*other
    return result
```

For non-supported types, you need to return the `NotImplemented` *singleton*, not raise an exception. This way Python will try the inverse operation too.

However, since the dispatch is going to key on the *wrong argument* (`self`) here anyway, you'll have to come up with your own single dispatch mechanism.

If you really want to use `@functools.singledispatch` you'd have to delegate to a regular function, with the arguments *inversed*:

```
@functools.singledispatch
def _vector_mul(other, self):
    return NotImplemented

class Vector(object):
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return _vector_mul(other, self)


@_vector_mul.register(int)
def _vector_int_mul(other, self):
    result = Vector(len(self))
    for j in range(len(self)):
        result[j] = self[j] * other
    return result
```

As for your updates using `__init__mul__`: `v * 3` is *not* translated to `v.__mul__(3)`. It is instead translated to `type(v).__mul__(v, 3)`, see [*Special method lookup*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup) in the Python datamodel reference. This *always* bypasses any methods set directly on the instance.

Here `type(v)` is `Vector`; Python looks up the *function*, it won't use a bound method here. Again, because `functools.singledispatch` dispatches on the *first* argument, always, you cannot use single dispatch directly on the methods of `Vector`, because that first argument is always going to be a `Vector` instance.

In other words, Python will *not* use the methods you set on `self` in `__init__mul__`; special methods are *never* looked up on the instance, see [*Special method lookup*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-lookup) in the datamodel documentation.

The `functools.singledispatchmethod()` option that Python 3.8 adds uses a *class* as the decorator which implements the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), just like methods do. This lets it then handle dispatch *before* binding (so before `self` would be prepended to the argument list) and then bind the registered function that the `singledispatch` dispatcher returns. The [source code for this implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b2fd32b2f041402bb9fc8607f01566c055aafed9/Lib/functools.py#L886-L920) is fully compatible with older Python versions, so you could use that instead:

```
from functools import singledispatch, update_wrapper

# Python 3.8 singledispatchmethod, backported
class singledispatchmethod:
    """Single-dispatch generic method descriptor.

    Supports wrapping existing descriptors and handles non-descriptor
    callables as instance methods.
    """

    def __init__(self, func):
        if not callable(func) and not hasattr(func, "__get__"):
            raise TypeError(f"{func!r} is not callable or a descriptor")

        self.dispatcher = singledispatch(func)
        self.func = func

    def register(self, cls, method=None):
        """generic_method.register(cls, func) -> func

        Registers a new implementation for the given *cls* on a *generic_method*.
        """
        return self.dispatcher.register(cls, func=method)

    def __get__(self, obj, cls):
        def _method(*args, **kwargs):
            method = self.dispatcher.dispatch(args[0].__class__)
            return method.__get__(obj, cls)(*args, **kwargs)

        _method.__isabstractmethod__ = self.__isabstractmethod__
        _method.register = self.register
        update_wrapper(_method, self.func)
        return _method

    @property
    def __isabstractmethod__(self):
        return getattr(self.func, '__isabstractmethod__', False)
```

and apply that to your `Vector()` class. You still have to register your `Vector` implementation for the single dispatch *after* the class has been created, because only then can you register a dispatch for the class:

```
class Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self._coords = [0] * d

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._coords[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._coords[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._coords)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Vector({self._coords!r})"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._coords)

    @singledispatchmethod
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return NotImplemented

    @__mul__.register
    def _int_mul(self, other: int):
        result = Vector(len(self))
        for j in range(len(self)):
            result[j] = self[j] * other
        return result

@Vector.__mul__.register
def _vector_mul(self, other: Vector):
    return sum(sc * oc for sc, oc in zip(self._coords, other._coords))
```

You could of course also create a subclass first and dispatch based on that, since dispatch works for subclasses too:

```
class _Vector(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self._coords = [0] * d

class Vector(_Vector):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._coords[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._coords[item]

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._coords)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({self._coords!r})"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._coords)

    @singledispatchmethod
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return NotImplemented

    @__mul__.register
    def _int_mul(self, other: int):
        result = Vector(len(self))
        for j in range(len(self)):
            result[j] = self[j] * other
        return result

    @__mul__.register
    def _vector_mul(self, other: _Vector):
        return sum(sc * oc for sc, oc in zip(self._coords, other._coords))
```

Comment: Could you define a static method `_mul_by_others(other, self)` for use with single dispatch, then have `def __mul__(self, other): return Vector._mul_by_other(other, self)`?

Comment: @chepner: I guess so; then at least the first argument is the other type.

Comment: @Sardathrion: ah, and I remember the **other** reason this doesn't work: special methods are looked up on the **type**, not the instance. So setting a `__mul__` attribute on the instance is going to be ignored and so is the singledispatch hook.

Comment: things have changed in 3.8 https://stackoverflow.com/q/24601722/5986907

Comment: @JoelBerkeley: thanks for the reminder, I've updated this answer to pull in that implementation.

Answer (score 4):

This is a little ugly, as you need to defer binding the implementation of `Vector`/`Vector` multiplication until after `Vector` is actually defined. But the idea is that the single-dispatch function needs the first argument to be of arbitrary type, so `Vector.__mul__` will call that function with `self` as the second argument.

```
import functools

class Vector:

    def __mul__(self, other):
        # Python has already dispatched Vector() * object() here, so
        # swap the arguments so that our single-dispatch works. Note
        # that in general if a*b != b*a, then the _mul_by_other
        # implementations need to compensate.
        return Vector._mul_by_other(other, self)

    @functools.singledispatch
    def _mul_by_other(x, y):
        raise NotImplementedError("Can't multiply vector by {}".format(type(x)))

    @_mul_by_other.register(int)
    def _(x, y):
        print("Multiply vector by int")

@Vector._mul_by_other.register(Vector)
def _(x, y):
    print("Multiply vector by another vector")

x = Vector()
y = Vector()
x * 3
x * y
try:
    x * "foo"
except NotImplementedError:
    print("Caught attempt to multiply by string")
```

Comment: I can use Vector in fun body, like Vector() . Indeed , the decorator to the methond in class is liking static var make self.__mul__ = @functools.singledispatch(self.__mul__) so this eval before a class was define ?

Comment: still have a fun outside the Vector , Can we have a way move it in class .

Comment: You can only use `Vector()` inside a method definition, because the name isn't actually looked up until you call the function *after* the (global) name `Vector` has been bound to the class you are defining. You can't use `Vector` at class scope, because the name doesn't exit yet, and Python doesn't have forward declarations.