# How to overload an __eq__ function that gets an object of the self class

Tags: python, single-dispatch

What i'm trying is to overload this function that is in Posicion class using singledispatch and trying to follow the OOP:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    if isinstance(other, Posicion):
        return other.get_posicion() == self.get_posicion()

    elif type(other) == tuple:
        assert len(other) == 2, "La tupla pasada por parámetro debe constar de dos elementos"
        self.verificar_formato(other[0], other[1])

        return (other[0].upper(), other[1]) == self.get_posicion()
```

I tried to apply singledispatch from functools library but i ran into the same errors as this question: [python3: singledispatch in class, how to dispatch self type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063788/python3-singledispatch-in-class-how-to-dispatch-self-type). because i'm trying to dispatch the self type. So i tryied

```
class _Posicion:
    def __init__(self, y, x):
    pass


class Posicion(_Posicion):
    def __init__(self, y, x):
        super()
        self.x = x
        self.y = y.upper()

    def get_posicion(self):
        return self.y, self.x

    @singledispatch
    def __eq__(self, other):
        raise NotImplementedError("Everything bad")
            

    @__eq__.register(_Posicion)
    def _(self, other):
        return other.get_posicion() == self.get_posicion()
    
    @__eq__.register(tuple)
    def _(self, other):
        assert len(other) == 2, "La tupla pasada por parametro debe constar de dos elementos"
        self.verificar_formato(other[0], other[1])

        return (other[0].upper(), other[1]) == self.get_posicion()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Posicion('a', 1) == ('a', 1)
```

But it always enter in the `@__eq__.register(_Posicion)` and if i deleted it always enter int the `def __eq__(self, other):`

I apologize, again, for the possibly bad wording of this question and thanks in advance for the help. If there is any other information that I should add, please let me know.

Comment: What's the actual error you're getting?  (Just copy and paste it instead of trying to describe it.)

Comment: Also, please post an MCVE

Comment: Also, the code you've pasted doesn't use `@singledispatch` at all.

Comment: Did you see the use of `singledispatchmethod` in the accepted answer to the question you linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a mix of duck-typing and single-dispatch.

```
@singledispatchmethod
def __eq__(self, other):
    try:
        f = other.get_posicion
    except AttributeError:
        return (self is other) or NotImplemented

    return self.get_posicion() == f()

@__eq__.register(tuple)
def _(self, other):
    assert len(other) == 2, "La tupla pasada por parámetro debe constar de dos elementos"
    self.verificar_formato(other[0], other[1])

    return (other[0].upper(), other[1]) == self.get_posicion()
```

This slightly weakens what you were trying: instead of insisting on comparing two `Posicion` instances, we allow comparing a `Posicion` to anything implementing a callable `get_posicion` attribute. If it fails, just compare based on object identity, otherwise call both object's method and compare the results.

The only explicit type we check for is `tuple`, avoiding the need to have a true reference to `Posicion` inside the class definition itself. (Though if you like, you can safely check `isinstance(other, Posicion)` *inside* the definition of `__eq__`; it's just as an argument to `singledispatchmethod` that `Posicion` is not yet defined.)