# Using @singledispatchmethod on __eq__(): Signature of "__eq__" incompatible with supertype "object"

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Here's a minimal reproducible example of what I'm trying to do ([mypy playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=a620d21948f7f7c3c22d204619fd084c)):

```py
from functools import singledispatchmethod


class C:
  
  value: int
  
  def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
    self.value = value
  
  @singledispatchmethod
  def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
    return NotImplemented
  
  @__eq__.register
  def _(self, other: C) -> bool:
    return self.value == other.value
    
  @__eq__.register
  def _(self, other: D) -> bool:
    return self.value == other.foo / 2
```

`D` is actually irrelevant to the problem, but here it is if you need it:

```py
class D:
  
  value: int
  
  def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
    self.value = value
  
  @property
  def foo(self) -> int:
    return 42 * self.value
```

mypy gives me the following error:

```
main.py:12: error: Signature of "__eq__" incompatible with supertype "object"  [override]
main.py:12: note:      Superclass:
main.py:12: note:          def __eq__(self, object, /) -> bool
main.py:12: note:      Subclass:
main.py:12: note:          singledispatchmethod[bool]
```

...which makes no sense at all. What can I do, other than using a `type: ignore` comment? I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68412432), but it is not about type hinting, and the only answer there [leads to the same error](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=cb623ab64e39dc43849bcde78e2b2d5b) (assuming I did not do anything incorrectly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type-checker is complaining because instances of `functools.singledispatchmethod` are not actually `Callable` ([it has no `__call__` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a46e96076898d126c9f276aef1934195aac34b4e/Lib/functools.py#L924-L974)). You eventually get a callable through dot-attribute-access from the [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) method [`__get__`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/559d31c4a33045310a30843dd7fac88a62cc5915/stdlib/functools.pyi#L194), but there is no attribute access here when you're simply defining the `__eq__` method in the class body.

The "solution" is to lie to the type-checker, pretending that `singledispatchmethod` is actually `Callable`. The following is a minimal implementation to make it work with your example (see [mypy-playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=ed023966ffd3d6a17bcb556379405dad)):

```py
from __future__ import annotations

import typing as t

from functools import singledispatchmethod as _singledispatchmethod


if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    import collections.abc as cx

    P = t.ParamSpec("P")
    T = t.TypeVar("T")

    class singledispatchmethod(_singledispatchmethod[T], t.Generic[P, T]):

        """
        Drop-in replacement for `functools.singledispatchmethod` when all the dispatched
        methods are of the same arity
        """

        def __init__(self, func: cx.Callable[t.Concatenate[t.Any, P], T], /) -> None: ...
        @t.type_check_only
        def __call__(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T: ...

else:
    singledispatchmethod: t.Final = _singledispatchmethod
```

```
>>> class C:
...     value: int
...
...     def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
...         self.value = value
...
...     @singledispatchmethod
...     def __eq__(self, other: object, /) -> bool:  # OK
...         return NotImplemented
```

Comment: This is a bit clunky for my taste, but if there is no better answer in a while I'll mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I wrote my `__eq__()` originally: Manual type checking.

```py
class C:

  def __eq__(self, other: object) -> bool:
    if isinstance(other, C):
      return ...
    
    if isinstance(other, D):
      return ...

    return NotImplemented
```

This is mypy-friendly and magic-free, although it might not look nice in a class which has other `@singledispatchmethod`. This is not preferable to me, but it might be for someone else.

Comment: you could alternatively use `match` with class patterns